# Parsley validate comma-separated email addresses

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, parsley.js, parsley

What I am doing is want to validate comma-separated email addresses using Parsley.

I have worked out custom validator and triggered email fields, but I got a error for custom validator function.

```
window.Parsley.
addValidator(
'emails', { 
requirementType: 'string', 
validateString: function(val){
var email, emails, ret, i, len; ret = true;
for(i = 0, len = emails.length; i < len; i++) {
email = emails[i];
ret = ret && this.type(email, 'email');
}
return ret;
},
message: {
en: 'This value should be a email address'
}
});
```

Then I got error message:

```
Uncaught TypeErro: this.type is not a function
   at f.validateString
   at f.validate(parsley.min.js:9)
   at _.validate
```

Anyone can help with this how to validate this email?

Comment: Best would be to fix Parsley to support `multiple`, see https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/885

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are expecting `this.type(email, 'email')` to be/do. `this` is the current `validator` object, probably not something you want to use.